# Cerrar varios dialogs en flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Como puedo hacer para cerrar todos los showdialogs de mi aplicacion? en este caso el _mostrarDialogConfirmacion es el dialog donde le solicito al usuario que confirme una consulta, cargandoDialog es otros dialog el cual lo muestro mientras se ejecuta la solicitud, una vez que termine de ejecutarse la solicitud quiero que los 2 dialog se cierren y que solamentemente me quede el dialog _mostrarDialogMensaje

```
_mostrarDialogConfirmacion(mensaje, BuildContext context, codLink, motivo){
      return showDialog(
      context: context, 
      builder: (context){
        return AlertDialog(
          title: const Text('Informacion', textAlign: TextAlign.center),
          content: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget> [
              Text(mensaje, textAlign: TextAlign.center)
            ],
          ),
          actions: <Widget> [
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                cargandoDialog(context);
                List<dynamic> ingresarReclamo1 = await ingresarReclamo.ingresarReclamo(codLink, titular, motivo);
                // ignore: use_build_context_synchronously
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                // ignore: use_build_context_synchronously
                _mostrarDialogMensaje(ingresarReclamo1[0].observaciones, ingresarReclamo1[0].validado, context);
              }, 
              child: const Text('Si')
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: ()=> Navigator.of(context).pop(),
              child: const Text('No')
            ),
          ],
        );
      }
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas reestructurar el llamado a los Diálogos, ya que los hecho dependientes uno del otro.

Retorna los resultados luego de llamar a tu API:

```dart
List<dynamic> ingresarReclamo1 = await ingresarReclamo.ingresarReclamo(codLink, titular, motivo);
                // ignore: use_build_context_synchronously
                Navigator.of(context).pop(ingresarReclamo);
```

Extrae la parte del llamado a `_mostrarDialogoMensaje`, así:

```dart
_mostrarDialogConfirmacion(mensaje, BuildContext context, codLink, motivo){
      return showDialog(
      context: context, 
      builder: (context){
        return AlertDialog(
          title: const Text('Informacion', textAlign: TextAlign.center),
          content: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget> [
              Text(mensaje, textAlign: TextAlign.center)
            ],
          ),
          actions: <Widget> [
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                cargandoDialog(context);
                List<dynamic> ingresarReclamo1 = await ingresarReclamo.ingresarReclamo(codLink, titular, motivo);
                // este pop es para sacar el primer dialogo
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                // con este sacas el segundo dialogo pero retornando los resultados
                Navigator.of(context).pop(ingresarReclamo1);
               
              }, 
              child: const Text('Si')
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: ()=> Navigator.of(context).pop(),
              child: const Text('No')
            ),
          ],
        );
      }
    );
  }
```

Haz las llamadas así:

```dart
final ingresarReclamo1 = await _mostrarDialogConfirmacion([tus parametros]);
if(ingresarReclamo1 != null){
                _mostrarDialogMensaje(ingresarReclamo1[0].observaciones, ingresarReclamo1[0].validado, context);
}
```